# S3 Buckets: Is looping over all the files and adding it up the only way to get the size of a bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, size, bucket

I have an S3 bucket and I'm using the S3 gem in rails.

I wouldn't mind checking the size of bucket every now and again.

Is the only way to do this loop over all the files in a bucket and add them up, or is there simple way to just get the bucket size?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

If you are on heroku or similar, you likely will want to launch the counting process on Ironworker (which I have tried and seems easy) to do that calculation. Heroku will only allow 40 second 'jobs', as its built for customer facing website stuff.